# Gym custom environment and PPO: trained agent taking always same action, any advice?

Tags: python, machine-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I have built a gym custom env and tested it with a dummy random agent: so far so good, what should happen happens correctly according to the rules of my game.

In short, my current spaces are:

```
action_space = MultiDiscrete([6, 60, 1122])
observation_space = Box(low=0, high=1122, shape=(1182,), dtype=np.float32)
```

Note that initially I wanted the following observation space:

```
observation_space = Dict({
    'list1' : Box(low=0, high=6, shape=(1, 1122), dtype=np.uint32),
    'list2' : Box(low=0, high=1122, shape=(1, 60), dtype=np.int32)
    })
```

...but since none of the Stable Baselines can handle Dict spaces, I had to concatenate both lists and use a Box taking the highest dimensions of both.

Then I tried to train the PPO Agent from Stable Baselines 3. I trained it on 1 million steps (about 10mn) and tested it on the environment: the trained agent always takes the same (silly) action and nothing happens. I repeated with the A2C agent and the same happened.

I am new to machine learning so I am a bit lost now and need some direction to move forward:

1. Does the problem come from my observation and/or action space? Do I need normalization?
2. Is the training way too short for that size of space?
3. Does the problem come from the hyperparameters?

Any advice welcome as I am stuck after a fairly long time making the environment... Thanks!

Comment: RL does have a problem with hyperparameter tuning. But PPO is generally robust to hyperparameters. I guess you could try training the agent with a normalised state and reward.